# how to get edittext values to be compared with database values in dialog box

Tags: android, database, dialog, android-edittext

I have a dialog box which asks the user for login credentials. I want to compare that password with the database value earlier stored for authentication. M not able to do that.
can anybody pls help.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu
    Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    String existPin=exist_pin.getText().toString();
    String confirmPin=new String();
    prefEditor.putString("ExistPin", existPin);
    prefEditor.commit();
    WayDataBase way=new WayDataBase(LoginActivity.this);
    String storedPin=way.getPin(confirmPin);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Data from database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(existPin.equals(storedPin))
    {
        d2.dismiss();
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ApplicantPage1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: R u getting any error?

Comment: are you able to get StoredPin from the database? which part in the if-else is being executed always? are you getting any error?

Comment: what is `String confirmPin=new String();`?

Comment: BTW, its best practice not to store PINs or passwords as plaintext in the database, you should store a cryptographic hash of the pin instead.  Otherwise anyone can get in by just grabbing the db off of the phone.  Also, newer Androids have user accounts and authentication, why not use that?

Comment: Please define "M not able to do that". What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: @ user1566160 .. yes ! the is unexpectedly stopped

Comment: @TheReader it does not enter the if loop..what is the problem i cant understand.

Comment: @RobinHood that is just a string to store the value coming from the database

Comment: share `getPin` method.

Comment: "Also, newer Androids have user accounts and authentication"  @Gabe Sechan can u give an example how to use that?? m just a rookie in android..i have no idea about wat ur saying!

Comment: `public String getPin(String pin)
 {
  Cursor cursor=db.query(pinTable, null, " Pin=?", new String[]{pin}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
         cursor.close();
         return "NOT EXIST";
        }
     cursor.moveToFirst();
  String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pin"));
  cursor.close();
  return password;    
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to compare within database, simply pass  entered `pin` in parameter within `getPin` function and check and return Boolean instead String something like below:

```
public boolean isValidPin(String pin) {// within database.

        boolean type = false;

        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                "select * from table where user_pin='" + pin+ "'", null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            type = true;
        }

        c.close();

        return type;

    }
```

Fetch pin from box and pass to function and later put condition and check boolean.

```
String pin=exist_pin.getText().toString();
boolean flag=isValidPin(String pin);


 if(flag)
    {
        d2.dismiss();
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ApplicantPage1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: `myDataBase.rawQuery` i am getting an error in this line  and in `boolean flag=isValidPin(String piN);' this line too

Comment: `The method rawQuery(String, null) is undefined for the type String`

Comment: `final Dialog d2=new Dialog(LoginActivity.this);
    d2.setContentView(R.layout.existing_user);
    d2.setTitle("Enter your Pin");
    final EditText exist_pin=(EditText)d2.findViewById(R.id.existing);
    final EditText invi=(EditText)d2.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button exist_submit_pin=(Button)d2.findViewById(R.id.exist_submit);
    exist_submit_pin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     ` this code creates dialog box let me noe if der is any issue @RobinHood

Comment: error is rectified but why does it close unexpectedly after clicking on `exist_submit_pin`

Comment: `03-26 07:12:12.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 07:12:12.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7719): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 07:12:12.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):  at com.android.lnt_form.WayDataBase.isValidPin(WayDataBase.java:147)
03-26 07:12:12.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):  at com.android.lnt_form.LoginActivity$3.onClick(LoginActivity.java:133)
03-26 07:12:12.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-26 07:12:12.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)


`